# Order by в селекте сильно тормозит поиск

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

при работе с oracle db столкнулся с проблемой, что при добавлении сортировки в запрос время его выполнения очень сильно возрастает.

При выполнении запроса `select * from ticket order by id;` в двух разных базах с одинаковой структурой, но разным наполнением, для каждого создаётся следующая структура запроса:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На сколько я понимаю торможение может быть связано с тем, что в нижнем примере используется 'table access(full)'.

Не могли бы вы помочь разобраться с чем может быть связано это расхождение и торможение?

Comment: индексы одинаковы в обеих БД? вроде скриншоты разное показывают

Comment: Полагаю как верно заметил @dSH в первом случае есть индекс, во втором нет, что хорошо видно по планам.

Comment: Индексы вроде есть и там и там
При селекте 
SELECT  *
FROM    all_indexes
WHERE   table_name = 'TICKET';
каждая из баз возвращает набор из 2х штук(TICKET_ID_PK, IDX_TICKET)

Comment: Так количество записей в первой таблице порядка 1500, а во второй 600тыс. И конечно с таким кол-вом записей будет работать гораздо медленнее, даже если пойдет по индексу. И возможно оракл вообще посчитал, что будет по индексу дольше выбирать (и возможно, он даже прав), поэтому перешел к сканированию таблицы. Возможно явно стоит ограничивать запрос по количеству записей, сомневаюсь, что вам нужно получать их все.  Или использовать подсказки оптимизатору вроде first_rows